# How to link openCv with Python3 in mac Os

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv, homebrew

I have two versions of python in my mac os, the first python2.7 which is the default that came with the system. Later I installed python3.7 that I use most of the time.

I have recently installed openCV using homebrew. 
When I'm using openCV with python2.7, it's working normally.

But the problem is when I try to use it with python3. Importing cv2 in python3 gives error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.
Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current 
information.

>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
import cv2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

Is there anything I can do so that I can link the installed openCV with python3 ??

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you build/install python after OpenCV, you mostly need to rebuild OpenCV for it to link with your new Python. If you install both of them with homebrew, you can reinstall OpenCV with option --with-python3 (I think). However, I would build OpenCV from source on MacOS using CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot give you specifics because your setup is not identical to mine, but I am sure we can get you sorted out.

Firstly, when you install packages, such as **OpenCV**, they tend to create a directory somewhere called `lib` which contains the C/C++ functions you can call from that package. Inside that directory, you normally find *"shared object libraries"* which traditionally end in *"XXX.so"* on macOS. More interestingly, they also contain a sub-directory called `site-packages` which contains the Python bindings (links). So, on my system, which is likely different from yours, I can find all those `site-packages` directories with:

```
find / -type d -name site-packages 2>/dev/null
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
...
...
/usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U5/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/Cellar/vips/8.6.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Hopefully, you can see that `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` is looking a very likely candidate for where all the Python v3.7 bindings for **OpenCV** should be.

Good, so now we know how to find the Python bindings, we need to tell Python that information. How? Well, not unreasonably, Python looks at an environment variable called `PYTHONPATH` to find its stuff. So, using our skill and judgement we need to marry up what we found in the first step with what we now know from the second step. So we do:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

And everything should work. All we need to do is put that in our login profile (probably `$HOME/.profile`) and we will be ready to go every time we log in.